# Magento2: How to set pagination for wishlist?

Tags: magento2, collection, wishlist, pagination

As my default wishlist collection which is coming from block is not working due to the applied theme in my magento2 site.

So, I applied the collection on my list.phtml file. And the problem is I need to apply pagination for this.

How to apply pagination for the wishlist listing page.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items $block */
$columns = $block->getColumns();
?>

<div class="products-grid wishlist wishlist_Alter">
    <?php if (count($block->getItems())): ?>
    <ol class="product-items">
        <?php 

        //NEW
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');  
        $customerData = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        $wishlist_collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist')->loadByCustomerId($customerData, true)->getItemCollection()->setOrder('added_at','DESC');

        //OLD DONT REMOVE 
        //$wishlist_collection = $block->getItems();

        foreach ($wishlist_collection as $item): ?>
            <?php //print_r($item->getAddedAt());?>
            <li data-row="product-item" class="product-item" id="item_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($item->getId()) ?>">
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                    <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
                        <?= $column->setItem($item)->toHtml();?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="message info empty">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('This Wish List has no Items')) ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
    <?= $column->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: wishlist pagination is in vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/view.phtml, you can sopy it to your theme and use     <div class="toolbar wishlist-toolbar"><?= $block->getChildHtml('wishlist_item_pager'); ?></div>

Comment: @EktaPuri Do you know how we can set custom pagination in my account wishlist product ? like I need to show first 9 product in 3 row then show "View More" button whene we click on view more display other 9 product

Comment: Please check this question
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/369138/magento-2-add-custom-pagination-in-wishlist-my-account-section