# Magento 2 Add custom pagination in Wishlist My Account Section

Tags: magento2.4, wishlist, pagination, myaccount

I have using Magento 2.4. I am trying to apply custom pagination in Wishlist my account section. Currently magento have default pagination based on page.

Initially I need to show first 9 product, then bottom show "View More" button, when we click on "**View More**" button then next 9 product will show.

If any have idea regarding pagination for Wishlist in my account section then share your idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have added custom Pagination on wishlist page instead of using php I have used javascipt for this and apply pagination on wishlist and ordered products collectively.

app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Wishlist/templates/item/list.phtml

```
 <?php
/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items $block */

$blockObj = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('CustomModule\CustomWishlist\Block\CustomWishlist');
$columns = $block->getColumns();

$allProducts = $blockObj->getAllProducts();

$searchedProducts = $blockObj->getAllProducts();

$isSearchResultsVisible = false;

?>
<div class="toolbar toolbar-custom">

    <div class="sorter">
        <label for="product-sorter" class="custom-sorter-label">Sort by:</label>
        <select id="product-sorter" class="custom-sorter-select">
            <option value="freq_ordered">Frequently Ordered</option>
            <option value="date_old_new">Date Ordered:Old-New</option>
            <option value="date_new_old">Date Ordered:New-Old</option>
            <option value="sort_az">Sort:A-Z</option>
            <option value="sort_za">Sort:Z-A</option>
        </select>
        <span onclick="clearFilters()"><a class="clear-filter-a custom-filter">Clear Filters</a></span>
    </div>

    <div class="pager">
        <!-- Add the product limit selector here -->
        <div class="limiter">
            <label for="product-limiter">Show:</label>
            <select id="product-limiter">
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>

            </select>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>




<div class="products-grid wishlist">
    <?php if (count($block->getItems())) : ?>
        <div class="wishlist-search-results" id="search-results">
            <?php if ($isSearchResultsVisible) : ?>
                <ol class="product-items">
                    <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $item) : ?>
                        <li data-row="product-item" class="product-item"
                            id="item_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($item->getId()) ?>">
                            <?php foreach ($columns as $column) : ?>
                                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                                    <?php $column->setItem($item)->toHtml(); ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div class="toolbar toolbar-custom">
    <div class="pager">
        <div class="pages">
            <div id="pagination" class="custom-wishlist-pagination items">
                <a href="#" id="prev-page" class="custom-wishlist-previous">Previous</a>
                <span id="page-numbers" class="page-num"></span>
                <a href="#" id="next-page" class="custom-wishlist-next">Next</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        var limit = 12;
        var totalPages = 0;
        var currentPage = parseInt(<?= (int)$block->getRequest()->getParam('p', 1) ?>);
        var formKey = '';

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?= $block->getUrl('customwishlist/ajax/form') ?>',
            type: 'GET', // Change type to 'GET'
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    formKey = data.form_key;
                    // Continue executing your code here or call the main function that requires formKey
                } else {
                    console.log('Error fetching form key');
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('AJAX error:' + textStatus);
                console.log('AJAX request failed. Response Text: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });

        function loadPage(page, sorter) {
            $('#loader').show(); // display the loader
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?= $block->getUrl('customwishlist/index/products') ?>',
                data: { p: page, limit: limit, sorter: sorter },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data.success) {
                        alert(data.message);
                        return;
                    }

                    var productList = $('#default-product-listings .product-items');
                    productList.empty();
                    $.each(data.products, function (i, product) {
                        var item = $('<li>').addClass('product-item');
                        var itemContent = $('<div>').addClass('product-item-info');


                        // Add product image
                        var productImage = $('<a>').addClass('product-item-photo').attr('href', product.url);
                        var imageContainer = $('<span>').addClass('product-image-container');
                        var imageWrapper = $('<span>').addClass('product-image-wrapper');
                        var image = $('<img>').attr('src', product.image).attr('alt', product.name);
                        imageWrapper.append(image);
                        imageContainer.append(imageWrapper);
                        productImage.append(imageContainer);
                        itemContent.append(productImage);

                        // Add product details
                        var productDetails = $('<div>').addClass('product-item-details');
                        var productName = $('<strong>').addClass('product-item-name');
                        var productNameLink = $('<a>').attr('href', product.url).text(product.name);
                        productName.append(productNameLink);
                        productDetails.append(productName);

                        // Add price
                        var priceBox = $('<div>').addClass('price-box');
                        var regularPrice = $('<span>').addClass('regular-price').attr('id', 'product-price-' + product.product_id);
                        var price = $('<span>').addClass('price').html(parseFloat(product.price.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')).toFixed(2));
                        regularPrice.append(price);
                        priceBox.append(regularPrice);
                        productDetails.append(priceBox);

                        itemContent.append(productDetails);

                        // Add quantity changer buttons
                        var quantityChanger = $('<div>').addClass('quantity-changer');
                        var decrementButton = $('<button>').addClass('decrement-qty').attr('type', 'button').text('-');
                        var quantityInput = $('<input>').attr('type', 'number').attr('name', 'qty').attr('min', '1').attr('value', '1').attr('title', 'Qty').addClass('input-text qty').attr('data-validate', '{"required-number":true}');
                        var incrementButton = $('<button>').addClass('increment-qty').attr('type', 'button').text('+');
                        quantityChanger.append(decrementButton, quantityInput, incrementButton);
                        itemContent.append(quantityChanger);

                        // Add add to cart form
                        var addToCartForm = $('<form>').attr('data-role', 'tocart-form').attr('action', '<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('checkout/cart/add')) ?>').attr('method', 'post');
                        var formKeyInput = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'form_key').val(formKey);
                        var productIdInput = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'product').val(product.product_id);
                        var addToCartButton = $('<button>').addClass('action tocart primary').attr('title', 'Add to Cart').attr('type', 'submit').text('Add to Cart');

                        addToCartForm.append(formKeyInput, productIdInput, addToCartButton);
                        itemContent.append(addToCartForm);
                        item.append(itemContent);
                        productList.append(item);
                    });

                    totalPages = Math.ceil(data.total / limit);
                    var pagination = $('#pagination');
                    pagination.empty();

                    if (currentPage > 1) {
                        var previousLink = $('<a>').addClass('action previous').text('Previous').attr('href', '<?= $block->getUrl('wishlist') ?>?p=' + (currentPage - 1));
                        pagination.append(previousLink);
                    }

                    for (var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
                        var link = $('<a>').addClass('item').text(i).attr('href', '<?= $block->getUrl('wishlist') ?>?p=' + i);
                        if (i === currentPage) {
                            link.addClass('current');
                        }
                        pagination.append(link);
                    }

                    if (currentPage < totalPages) {
                        var nextLink = $('<a>').addClass('action next').text('Next').attr('href', '<?= $block->getUrl('wishlist') ?>?p=' + (currentPage + 1));
                        pagination.append(nextLink);
                    }

                    currentPage = page;

                    var newUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?p=' + page;
                    history.pushState(null, null, newUrl);

                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                    $('#loader').hide(); // hide the loader after successful data load
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).on('click', '.increment-qty', function () {
            var qtyInput = $(this).siblings('.qty');
            var qty = parseInt(qtyInput.val());
            qtyInput.val(qty + 1);
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.decrement-qty', function () {
            var qtyInput = $(this).siblings('.qty');
            var qty = parseInt(qtyInput.val());
            if (qty > 1) {
                qtyInput.val(qty - 1);
            }
        });

        $('#product-limiter').on('change', function () {
            limit = parseInt($(this).val());
            loadPage(1);
        });
        $('#product-sorter').on('change', function () {
            var sorter = $(this).val();
            loadPage(currentPage, sorter);
        });
        var sorter = $('#product-sorter').val();
        loadPage(currentPage, sorter);

        loadPage(currentPage);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not working. Need to add view more button then button click next 9 product will show again click view more then 9 more product will so etc...